android webview unable to invoke javascript function from native code
I am trying to invoke a javascript function from Android native code which is supposed to show an alert. When I try to run the app the alert never shows up in the webview. The flow is that on my web page on a button click i show welcome message(javascript to native invocation) to the user and then i want to hide that message after its done displaying ! I am able to observe the message being shown but when i try to call the function to hide the message which is trying to do the reverse to invoke some javascript function nothing happens.
class WebActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  val DATA =```<html lang="en">
        <head>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            function callWelcome() {
              WebInterfaceHandler.showWelcome();
            }
            function hideWelcome() {
              alert('hiding welcome');
            }
          </script>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
          <title>Welcome</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div> <button onclick="callWelcome()">callWelcome</button></div>
        </body>
     </html>```

  private lateinit var webView: WebView
  private val handler = Handler()

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setTheme(R.style.NoActionBar)
    val viewModel: WebViewModel by viewModels()
    setupWebView()
    webView.loadData(DATA, "text/html", "base64")
    // observe when callWelcome was shown via button click and then change state to hide welcome
    viewModel.callWelcomeWasShown.observe(this) { response: String ->
      webView.let {
        handler.post {
          // this is supposed to call javascript function hideWelcome which shows alert BUT NOTHING HAPPENS AND THE ALERT NEVER GETS INVOKED 
    // call js function -> javascript:hideWelcome();
          it.loadUrl("javascript:$response") 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

